# Eclipse fails to download Android SDK platforms on non-root Mac user

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

I'm running a Mac with the newest OS X Mountain Lion.

I didn't have this problem before, but then I needed to enable the root user. Since then (just assuming, because it could be caused by something else) I can't download any content from the Android SDK Manager. It fails with a message (Permission denied). I'm able to do the update from the root user. That's kinda problematic. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete eclipse, download it again and install all content all over on my standard account. Then it worked

Answer (score 1):

Find out where your Android SDK is installed via Eclipse Preferences. Change the permissions of that folder to globally accessible `chmod -R o+rwx <folder path>` (or at least make it accessible to your user account)

You might need sudo for that chmod call.

A more secure option would be to copy the entire folder to your own home directory somewhere and use that as Android SDK path in eclipse.